# Forcing RadComboBox drop down direction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik, radcombobox

Users are desiring that the drop down window of a RadComboBox go up instead of down, regardless of where on the screen they are.  Not sure why, but how would you implement this?

Note: I have a RadComboBox with a custom template, not the default implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to disable screen boundary detection. Then you can set the expand direction to "Up", e.g:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server"
    EnableScreenBoundaryDetection="false" ExpandDirection="Up" />
```

Update: it seems this also works without disabling `EnableScreenBoundaryDetection`.