# Any one know how to create combo box bottom to top in asp.net telerik asp.net AJAX UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, telerik

Usually all combo box will be display top to bottom, But i want to know how display **bottom to top** approach.

I am using telerik asp.net AJAX UI controls. Or suggest me some other way to show.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about menu direction? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/direction

Answer (score 1):

Setting ExpandDirection="Up" property of the combobox should help.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180125/438780